# dynamic editing in linux

Tags: grep, edit

I am fairly new to linux. What I am looking for is a way to edit a file without opening it, but by just editing grep output.

So if I do

```
grep find_me allMyfiles
```

and get the output

```
file_1: this is find_me line in file_1
file_2: this is find_me line in file_2
```

I would like to edit a certain line without having to open the file, so e.g. changing the first hit to

```
file_1: this is find_me line in file_1 including my edits
```

and having this change being saved in file_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define what "opening a file" means to you.

But something needs to do the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall. (There is not way to read inside a file without using that `open(2)` syscall).

If you want to edit some file programmatically (inside your shell script), consider using the [GNU ed](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html), or [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) or [GNU emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) (with `emacs --batch` or `emacs --eval` ....)

Perhaps [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) could be useful.

Reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Bash Scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) should be helpful.

Comment: Then I have answered your question: use `ed` or `sed` or `emacs --batch` or `emacs --eval`

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at your proposed solutions

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/find_me/s/$/ including my edits/' filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at sed